# In case of high nibble first zero should be added first

Tags: ruby

I am using ruby 1.9.2 and this is what I found.

```
> ['A'].pack('H')
=> "\xA0"
```

Since `H` takes high nibble first and since the input `A` is only one nibble the additional nibble should be padded at the front. Which means the above code should be same as

```
> ['0A'].pack('H')
```

But it seems I am missing something. Anyone cares to explain.

Since the answer of the first case is `\xA0` it is clear that the zero is being padded to the right. However when we are dealing with high nibble first then `A` should be same as `0A` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pack half a byte, one nibble, that's what you'll get. You need to specify how long your input string is in nibbles:

```
'X'.unpack('h')
# => ["8"]
'X'.unpack('h2')
# => ["85"]

'X'.unpack('H')
# => ["5"]
'X'.unpack('H2')
# => ["58"]
```

To `pack` is to do the opposite of `unpack`, so don't omit the length argument.

Comment: Thanks. However the question is why `['A'].pack('H2') => "\xA0"` is adding a zero at the end. I think in this case a zero should be added before A which should lead to decimal value 10 and the output should be `\n`.

Comment: It's not "adding a zero", it's creating a single byte with the value `0xA0`, and since the first four bits are the high nibble, that's where the `A` goes. `['A0'].pack('H2')` is the same as `['0A'].pack('h2')` so if you need it in high-low order, not low-high, use `h` instead of `H`. I don't know why you're expecting "high first" to populate the low nibble if given just one character.